# Angular scope variable storing different value compared to api response

Tags: angularjs, unix-timestamp

I am facing a very strange problem today with Angular, I have an api call whose response is giving (this is what i got from raw api call in new tab)

> { "startTime" : 1524021720000, "endTime" : 1524022800000 }

but after making an http call and storing response in $scope.dataSet variable this is what i am getting,

> { "startTime" : 1524001920000, "endTime" : 1524003000000 }

Below is the code snippet:

```
$http({url: testDetailsUrl, method: 'GET'})
  .then(function(response) {
      $scope.dataset = response.data;
      console.log($scope.dataset.startTime, $scope.dataset.endTime);
}
```

I wanted to filter out value through angular pipe to show it as a time string, but i got strange results bucause of this change in variable values. Can anybody please explain me what happened here?
PS: I am using angular 1.4.9 and my browser's timezone is GMT+5:30..

Comment: post your code please.

Comment: in browser network tab, what is the response you get?

Comment: @fatemefazli The network tab also showing the wrong values. However as i mentioned, while querying the same api call separately in new tab the response is correct.

Comment: are you sure you are getting the same url? it would be good if you post any code or screen shot of both.

Comment: @super cool i checked as there are no two log entries, the request fired only once.

Comment: would be good if you post image or console and network or url.

Answer (score 0):

According to me it is nothing to do with your browser's timezone GMT+5:30. I even faced similar issue, where WEB API is giving me new value(xyz) but in the $scope previous value(abc) used to display in the front end.

To fix this issue you can use below code,

```
$http({url: testDetailsUrl, method: 'GET', cache: false, headers: {
            'Cache-Control' : 'no-cache'
        }})
```